# Finding charaters to right of second period - Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ table that looks like this

```
| website           | 
| --------          |
| xyz.com           |
| abc.xyz.com       |
| 123.abc.xyz.com   |
| 098.com           |
```

I want to clean up this table so that I only get the domain. In my ideal world I want to execute the following steps.

1. For each row - Count number of '.'
2. If there are more than 1 '.', THEN extract everything to the right of the second '.' from the right. So 'abc.xyz.com' gets extracted as 'xyz.com'
3. If there is just 1 '.', THEN do nothing and give me the input as output. So 'xyz.com' gets outputed as 'xyz.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select website, net.reg_domain(website) as result
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Wow. What a life saver! You literally saved me many hours of manual cleanup on excel with this one simple function.

Answer (score 0):

A simplier approach to extract only the domain using [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```sql
with sample as (
  select 'xyz.com' as website
  union all
  select 'abc.xyz.com' as website
  union all
  select '123.abc.xyz.com' as website
  union all
  select '098.com' as website
)
select 
regexp_extract(website, r"[\w]+\.[\w]+$") as website
from sample;
```

Output:

```
xyz.com
xyz.com
xyz.com
098.com
```

Explanation:

- `[\w]+` will match any sequence of one or more letters
- `\.` will match a single dot
- `[\w]+$`  will match any sequence of one or more letters only on the end of the string